Issue with aws glue job On prem oracle table to cloud
I am facing a writer issue to an iceberg table using the aws glue job . My use case is to read an oracle table from onprem and write to iceberg table using aws glue. read from onprem table is good, but write is causing the error
I have added the job parameter as data lake formats as iceberg . The table already exists in the database with sufficient permission
2024-06-27 15:59:56,539 ERROR [main] glue.ProcessLauncher (Logging.scala:logError(77)): Error from Python:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/test_iceberg.py", line 66, in <module>
    glueContext.write_data_frame.from_catalog(
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.10/site-packages/awsglue/dataframewriter.py", line 20, in from_catalog
    return self._glue_context.write_data_frame_from_catalog(frame, db, table_name, redshift_tmp_dir,
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.10/site-packages/awsglue/context.py", line 413, in write_data_frame_from_catalog
    return DataSink(j_sink, self).writeDataFrame(frame, self)
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.10/site-packages/awsglue/data_sink.py", line 35, in writeDataFrame
    return DataFrame(self._jsink.pyWriteDataFrame(data_frame._jdf, glue_context._glue_scala_context, callsite(), info), self._sql_ctx)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 190, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 330, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o148.pyWriteDataFrame. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method pyWriteDataFrame([class com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicFrame, class com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)



code
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext ,DynamicFrame
from awsglue.job import Job
import os
import boto3
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame, SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkConf 

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
os.environ["PYSPARK_PYTHON"] = sys.executable
os.environ["PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON"] = sys.executable
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])
aws_account_id = boto3.client('sts').get_caller_identity().get('Account')

catalog_name = "glue_catalog"
warehouse_path = f"s3://s3-bucket/d_extract/"


args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

conf = (
                SparkConf()
                .set("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInRead", "LEGACY")  # test
                .set("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInWrite", "LEGACY")  # test
                .set("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInRead", "LEGACY")  # test
                .set("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true")
                .set("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true")
                .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.server-side-encryption-algorithm", "AES256")
                .set("spark.sql.extensions", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions")
                .set("spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog")
                .set("spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.warehouse", warehouse_path)
                .set("spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.catalog-impl", "org.apache.iceberg.aws.glue.GlueCatalog")
                .set("spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.io-impl", "org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO")
                .set("spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.glue.lakeformation-enabled", "true")
                .set("spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.glue.id", aws_account_id)
            )
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf).getOrCreate()

glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
#spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
logger = glueContext.get_logger()
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)


connection_options = {
        "useConnectionProperties": "true",
        "dbtable": "db.table_nm",
        "connectionName": "db_conn",
        "hashfield": "OPEN_DT_ID" ,
         "hashpartitions": 7 ,
    }

glue_df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        connection_type="oracle",
        connection_options=connection_options,
        transformation_ctx="glue_df",
    )
    
glue_df.show(5)



glueContext.write_data_frame.from_catalog(
    frame=glue_df,
    database="d_extract",
    table_name="aws_table_name",
    transformation_ctx = "glue_df"
)
job.commit()


Do you have the same data type for column in d_extract as in table_nm?

Yes. I have same structure exactly similar

The columns are in the same order?

Can you do a glue_df.printSchema() before glueContext.write_data_frame.from_catalog method call just to check the column types?

as per aws support we have scp at org level which restricts the s3 put call while iceberg dumps the metadata infromation
